# How to show different images in uimageview on button click

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimageview

I've developed an iOS app with a button, segment control and a uiimageview.  In the assets folder, there are 26 pictures, named card1 to card26.  If I use the below code, it displays each of the 26 images in a random order.  How would I flip that code to show each picture in order of image name, card1...card2...etc?  I've searched for the last hour and cant find exactly what I'm looking for.  I appreciate the help.

```
let Number = Int.random(in: 2...26) 
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "card\(Number)")
```

Comment: Create a property of your VC to hold the current number: `var number = 1`.  Then In the `@IBAction` for your button, increment this number and if it's 27, set it back to 1. Use `number` to set the image just as you did before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a property of your `ViewController` called `number` to keep track of the current `number`.  Increment it in the `@IBAction` and set it back to `1` when it reaches `27`:

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    var number = 1

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "card1")
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // use % (mod function) to keep result in the range 1...26
        number = number % 26 + 1
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "card\(number)")
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could simply have your button action increment `number` and use a property observer on `number` to update the `image`:

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

    var number = 1 {
        didSet {
            if number == 27 {
                number = 1
            }
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "card\(number)")
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

         imageView.image = UIImage(named: "card1")
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        number = number + 1
    }
}
```